# MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: '535: 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, user is locked by your organization's security defaults policy

Tags: smtp, .net-6.0, smtpclient

I'm trying to send an email from my .Net 6 application from my office365 email account using following configuration following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365)

```json
"EmailConfiguration": {
   "From": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
   "SmtpServer": "smtp.office365.com",
   "Port": 25, // tried port 587 also
   "Username": "XXXXXXXXX",
   "Password": "XXXXXXXX"
}
```

And this is my code to send the email:

```cs
using var client = new SmtpClient();
try
{
    client.Connect(_emailConfig.SmtpServer, _emailConfig.Port, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
    //client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
    client.Authenticate(_emailConfig.UserName, _emailConfig.Password);

    client.Send(mailMessage);
}
catch
{
    //log an error message or throw an exception or both.
    throw;
}
finally
{
    client.Disconnect(true);
    client. Dispose();
}
```

But I'm getting this error on `client.Authenticate` call

> MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: '535: 5.7.139 Authentication
> unsuccessful, user is locked by your organization's security defaults
> policy. Contact your administrator.
> [PN2PR01CA0027.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2023-12-10T12:33:11.474Z
> 08DBF8259ECF3F85]'

We tried to check everything in the admin panel to see if the particular email account or user is locked but we found nothing like that.

I have enabled the `Authenticated SMTP` setting for that particular email account using the [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission)

I tried to disable that setting also, but then I started getting an error for Authentication failure.

Can anybody guide me please to what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and found that you have to enable conditional access in Entra. This is NOT recommended by Microsoft, but it is the only way I have been able to get this to work correctly.

To do this:

- Sign in to the Microsoft Entra admin center as at least a Security Administrator.
- Browse to Identity > Overview > Properties.
- Select Manage security defaults. (It's at the bottom of page)
- Set Security defaults to Enabled.
- Select Save.

The official Microsoft instructions to do this are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/security-defaults

You also have to turn off multi-factor authentication for the user you are wanting to send emails as. There might be other ways around this part with app keys or something, but I am not 100% sure on that one. I am sure someone will pipe up here and mention it.

Comment: "Set Security defaults to Enabled." - shouldn't that be Disabled? That's when they ask for the reason for disabling, and Conditional Access is one of them.

Comment: Thank you! I enabled it the other day. Shouldn't have done that :)

Comment: I have similar issue, I have done all the processes you have told, but still same. In my case its' working fine on my machine, my friend's machine, When I try to send email from our servers (transporting the build version of the code) then it failed.