# Django/ Office 365 : 535, b"5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, user is locked by your organization's security defaults policy

Tags: django, email, oauth-2.0, smtp, office365

Running into the following error when trying to send email with Django:

`535, b"5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, user is locked by your organization's security defaults policy.`

Here is my current config:

```
#Emailing Settings
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.office365.com'
EMAIL_FROM = 'email@email.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@email.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS= True
```

This error was raised here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1469524/error-when-testing-smtp-for-django-website

The irony of the answer provided by Microsoft is to suggest to disable the security default and also adding "not recommend".

It seems the error is specific to Microsoft and comes from the use of SMTP, which MS's security doesnt like and encourage the use of OAuth.

Can someone suggest an approach that worked for them? Did you disable the security defaults (for the specific email): is it risky? Did you implement OAuth and if so what steps did you take?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: '535: 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, user is locked by your organization's security defaults policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77634836/mailkit-security-authenticationexception-535-5-7-139-authentication-unsuccess)

Comment: Do you have a 2FA set up for the tenant? If so, you need to turn it off.

Comment: Hi @Eugene I did see that post. I'm not the admin on the office 365 side and was told to find another way rather than disabling the default security settings. Currently considering using Sendgrid instead. A bit annoying as it involved more integration. Do you have any views on this approach?

Comment: It requires additional steps because it is not safe to leave a possible hole. If anybody steals your password and loging - they can spam others or just impersonate you. That is why 2FA is recommended nowadays, only having a password is not enough these days.